# Angular Material Design - page footer issue - double scrollbar

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a page footer implemented as follows.

HTML

```
<footer class="app-footer-main">
  <section class="app-footer-items">
    ...
  </section>
</footer>
```

Styles

```
.app-footer-main {
  background-color: black;
}

.app-footer-items {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  font-size: small;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I want this footer to be placed at the bottom of each page in the application. If the page content is large I would like to scroll down the page and see the footer at the end of the page.

HMTL that renders the main content of the application where the footer is embedded.

```
  <mat-sidenav-container fullscreen class="sidenav-container">
    <!-- Collapsible side content -->
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav [mode]="'side'" class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <mat-nav-list>
        ...
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <!-- End Collapsible side content -->
    <!-- Main Content Area -->
    <div class="main-content">
      <div class="mat-app-background">
        <!-- Routed view  -->
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Main Content Area -->
    <app-footer #footer></app-footer>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

Style for the main content:

```
.main-content {
    padding: {
        top: 0;
        left: 15px;
        right: 15px;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    @include breakpoint($narrow-devices) {
        padding: {
            left: 15px;
            right: 15px;
        }
    }
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-sidenav-container[fullscreen] {
    top: 55px;
    @include breakpoint($narrow-devices) {
        top: 64px;
    }
}

// :host /deep/ is used to allow styling child components when using emulated view encapsulation.
:host ::ng-deep .mat-sidenav-content {
  transform: none !important;
}

.main-content {
    & ::ng-deep .outlet,
    & ::ng-deep .maxed-width {
        @include breakpoint($narrow-devices) {
                max-width: $page-max-width;
                margin: {
                    left: auto;
                    right: auto;
                }
        }
    }
}

.sidenav-container {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Issue with this approach is that there are double scrollbars on the page, as you can see on the attached screenshot. One for the main content of the page and other for the footer. How can I resolve this issue please?

[image: Double scrollbar on the page.]

Comment: Please create a stackblitz/codesandbox as this issue required debugging details.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue. Following code worked for me: Provide margin-top should be equal to the height of the footer. I used 'vh' instead of '%' for height in main div and footer that did the trick for me.

```
   .footer {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 20vh;
      margin-top: 20vh;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      bottom: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Did not work I'm afraid. Double scrollbar is still persistent. I will post an answer to my question as and when I come up with a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this issue by re-structuring the HTML as follows:

```
  <mat-sidenav-container fullscreen class="sidenav-container">
    <!-- Collapsible side content -->
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav [mode]="'side'" class="navbar" role="navigation">
      <mat-nav-list>
        ...
      </mat-nav-list>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <!-- End Collapsible side content -->
    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <!-- Main Content Area -->
        <div class="main-content">
          <div class="mat-app-background">
            <!-- Routed view  -->
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Main Content Area -->
        <app-footer #footer></app-footer>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
```

Change the `height` property in main-content CSS class to `min-height` as follows:

```
.main-content {
    padding: {
        top: 0;
        left: 15px;
        right: 15px;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    @include breakpoint($narrow-devices) {
        padding: {
            left: 15px;
            right: 15px;
        }
    }
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: does giving min-height in percentage work when zooming out  the screen ? I believe it should not.

Comment: @Rajat I had to tweak the min-height as follows; `calc(100% - 45px);` Where footer height is set as 45px. This works very well.